# How to open FB.login in lightbox instead popup

Tags: facebook-graph-api

It's possible to do?

if yes, how can i do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

No, it isn't. Facebook only allows you to open the login dialog in a popup.

Comment: This is correct. Only popup and full-page views are allowed for the login dialog.

Comment: Do you know why did they go for the popup window instead of the lightbox-iframe solution?